# Understanding Scoring in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to Solr and trying to index some documents where each document is a json. There are some documents whose score should be high but have a very low score.The field type for which I am querying is text_general.
Need some understanding of the fields like tfNorm,field-length etc.

Attached is the result of the debug query.

```
"718152d81b4db95f":"\n1.0891073 = sum of:\n  0.5578956 = weight(channel_genre:sports in 53) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.5578956 = score(doc=53,freq=11.0 = termFreq=11.0\n), product of:\n      0.29769886 = idf(docFreq=223, docCount=300)\n      1.8740268 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        11.0 = termFreq=11.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        256.0 = fieldLength\n  0.53121173 = weight(channel_genre:kids in 53) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.53121173 = score(doc=53,freq=12.0 = termFreq=12.0\n), product of:\n      0.27996004 = idf(docFreq=227, docCount=300)\n      1.8974556 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        12.0 = termFreq=12.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        256.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "7071fa048f60603":"\n1.0834496 = sum of:\n  0.5491592 = weight(channel_genre:sports in 75) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.5491592 = score(doc=75,freq=23.0 = termFreq=23.0\n), product of:\n      0.29769886 = idf(docFreq=223, docCount=300)\n      1.8446804 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        23.0 = termFreq=23.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        655.36 = fieldLength\n  0.53429043 = weight(channel_genre:kids in 75) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.53429043 = score(doc=75,freq=29.0 = termFreq=29.0\n), product of:\n      0.27996004 = idf(docFreq=227, docCount=300)\n      1.9084525 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        29.0 = termFreq=29.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        655.36 = fieldLength\n",
  "17e4a205707dc974":"\n1.0824875 = sum of:\n  0.62048614 = weight(channel_genre:sports in 64) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.62048614 = score(doc=64,freq=24.0 = termFreq=24.0\n), product of:\n      0.29769886 = idf(docFreq=223, docCount=300)\n      2.0842745 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        24.0 = termFreq=24.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        163.84 = fieldLength\n  0.46200132 = weight(channel_genre:kids in 64) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.46200132 = score(doc=64,freq=4.0 = termFreq=4.0\n), product of:\n      0.27996004 = idf(docFreq=227, docCount=300)\n      1.6502403 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        4.0 = termFreq=4.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        163.84 = fieldLength\n",
  "1a48c3a658cc07af":"\n1.0820175 = sum of:\n  0.58498204 = weight(channel_genre:sports in 59) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.58498204 = score(doc=59,freq=16.0 = termFreq=16.0\n), product of:\n      0.29769886 = idf(docFreq=223, docCount=300)\n      1.9650128 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        16.0 = termFreq=16.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        256.0 = fieldLength\n  0.49703547 = weight(channel_genre:kids in 59) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.49703547 = score(doc=59,freq=8.0 = termFreq=8.0\n), product of:\n      0.27996004 = idf(docFreq=227, docCount=300)\n      1.7753801 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        8.0 = termFreq=8.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        256.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "e073dacae12f494b":"\n1.0804946 = sum of:\n  0.5613358 = weight(channel_genre:sports in 17) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.5613358 = score(doc=17,freq=19.0 = termFreq=19.0\n), product of:\n      0.29769886 = idf(docFreq=223, docCount=300)\n      1.8855827 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        19.0 = termFreq=19.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        455.1111 = fieldLength\n  0.51915884 = weight(channel_genre:kids in 17) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.51915884 = score(doc=17,freq=17.0 = termFreq=17.0\n), product of:\n      0.27996004 = idf(docFreq=227, docCount=300)\n      1.8544034 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        17.0 = termFreq=17.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        455.1111 = fieldLength\n",
  "c69628bbb1d9f3ca":"\n1.0785265 = sum of:\n  0.55884564 = weight(channel_genre:sports in 96) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.55884564 = score(doc=96,freq=14.0 = termFreq=14.0\n), product of:\n      0.29769886 = idf(docFreq=223, docCount=300)\n      1.877218 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        14.0 = termFreq=14.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        334.36734 = fieldLength\n  0.51968086 = weight(channel_genre:kids in 96) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n    0.51968086 = score(doc=96,freq=13.0 = termFreq=13.0\n), product of:\n      0.27996004 = idf(docFreq=227, docCount=300)\n      1.8562679 = tfNorm, computed from:\n        13.0 = termFreq=13.0\n        1.2 = parameter k1\n        0.75 = parameter b\n        142.80667 = avgFieldLength\n        334.36734 = fieldLength\n",
```

According to the query that I have submitted the score of "c69628bbb1d9f3ca" should be higher than the other documents.What I am missing here to understand. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the debug you are querying the *channel_genre* field. For field *c69628bbb1d9f3ca* the score is affected by the number of terms and the field length but the scores are only marginally different in the results.

- term frequency is measure of how often a term appears in the field, more matches, the more important the result
- field length - shorter fields are less likely to contain hits so get a boost.

Are you using the standard query parser?

Perhaps you can explain why you think the results are incorrect?

Also consider omitNorms="true" if you want to disable length normalization.

Comment: In Solr the query is - channel_genre:'Sports' AND channel_genre:'Kids' i.e. (Number of users who watch both kids and Sports pre-dominantly)
Number of Returned Documents: 150
Maximum-Score: 1.2256454
I had specifically added 100 users who watch both Kids and Sports often to validate whether they fall in Top 100. But there are 6 users who fall below 100 and "c69628bbb1d9f3ca" is one such user. Just wanted to understand whether the field length makes a huge impact on the score or not.

Comment: Given the closeness of the scores of the fields you posted I would say that it does in this case.

Comment: BTW did you consider trying omitNorms="true" on your field, (should disable length normalization)

Comment: Yes I tried with omitNorms="true".Now the result is as expected :)